# Modal form don't submit data for mysql using materialize css

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker, materialize

I'm using a modal form and trying submit data for mysql database, but when i click on the submit button, the modal close and the db don't received anything.

example:

```
<form action="proc_cad_os.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input name="num" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label>Nº - OS</label>
                    </div>  
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn light white-text red" >Cancelar</button> &nbsp
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light green" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Gerar OS<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The same problem[Unable to insert data in materialized modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811287/unable-to-insert-data-into-mysql-from-a-materialized-modal-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [materialize modal in Meteor how to trigger modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698655/materialize-modal-in-meteor-how-to-trigger-modal)

Comment: I think it was because your submit button was outside the `form`  tag. I've updated your quation, and Now it should work.

Comment: Also there should not be two submit buttons, so Cancel button should not have type="submit"

Comment: place your submit button inside the form tag, and there should be only one submit button for a single form

Comment: i did it, put the button inside form tag and let only single submit on form, but didn't worked. :/ the modal just close.

Comment: no sucess yet, i'm thinking about change the framework